# Can a bowler change hands for different deliveries in the same over?

Tags: rules, cricket

Can a bowler, within the same over, bowl three balls with their right hand and three balls with their left hand?

Can they do this alternating sides or must they complete all deliveries with each hand consecutively before changing?

Answer (score 2):

Bowlers must inform the Umpire, who in turn informs the batsmen of what side of the wicket they will bowl from and from which hand when they begin their spell. They need to inform the Umpire, who informs the batsmen if they want to change it but can do so as often as they like. That is all though, the style of bowling need not be declared, just the side of the wicket and hand. If he didn't inform it would be declared as a no-ball.

So a bowler a can switch hands, but with prior information to the standing umpire for the change.

Please see this [link](https://www.sportskeeda.com/slideshow/cricket-5-cricketers-bowled-both-hands?imgid=78899)

Comment: This would be a great answer if you could add a reference to the Laws of the Game which specify this.

Comment: Additionally, umpiring practice would say that if the bowler had a consistent plan, such as I will bowl right arm over to bat a and left arm over to the Bat B, it would be normal to say it once and the umpire to tell the bats once.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question:

> Can a bowler, within the same over, bowl three balls with their right hand and three balls with their left hand?

Yes, so long as the bowler notifies the umpire (who will then notify the striker) before they change their mode of delivery - either from left hand to right hand or vice versa, or from over the wicket to round the wicket or vice versa. This is covered by [Law 21.1.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/):

> The umpire shall ascertain whether the bowler intends to bowl right handed or left handed, over or round the wicket, and shall so inform the striker.
>
> It is unfair if the bowler fails to notify the umpire of a change in his/her mode of delivery.  In this case the umpire shall call and signal No ball.

The second part:

> Can they do this alternating sides or must they complete all deliveries with each hand consecutively before changing?

Yes, they can alternate sides so long as they notify the umpire before each ball; there is no restriction in Law 21 or elsewhere as to the number of times that a change of mode of delivery can be made during an over.

Answer (score -1):

At the start of the over bowler notifies the umpire by

> "Right arm over the wicket"

Whenever the bowler want to change its bowling side , one can change by notifying

> "side change or Right arm over the wicket "

In the same way bowler can change its arm by simply notifying the field umpire.

> "Left arm over the wickets".

But it is quiet tough for a regular bowler to throw a legal delivery by different hand.